# Dynamically insert non-database value in ItemTemplate for ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, listviewitem, asp.net-4.5

I have a listview populated from the database. I also have a dynamically calculated value (users inputted postcode relative distance to all database postcode)

I tried adding a label which I can successfully access in the `ItemTemplate` for the `ListView` through the `ItemDataBound` event:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
  {
    if (CategoryList.SelectedIndex == 5)
    {
      var lb = e.Item.FindControl("lbPostcodeDistance") as Label;
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPostcode.Text))
      {
        lb.Text = "Distance from: " + tbPostcode.Text;
        lb.Visible = true;            
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above works fine, however, I need to dynamically add an actual value to `lb.Text`.

The value is calculated in my `public IEnumerable<...> ListView1_GetData()`, here is a snippet of code:

```
var inRangeWalks = new List<InRangeWalks>();            
foreach (var walk in grabAllWalks)
{
  double dis = //calculation here
  if (dis <= radius)
  {
    inRangeWalks.Add(new InRangeWalks(dis, walk));
  }
}

inRangeWalks.Sort((x, y) => x.DistanceFromPostcode.CompareTo(y.DistanceFromPostcode));
}
return inRangeWalks.Select(x => x.Walk); //ListView only wants walks, thus returned ordered Walks.
```

The code above works perfectly, but I need to add the `dis` value to each `item` in the `ItemTemplate`. I've been trying to do it using the `ItemDataBound` event but I am not sure if this is correct, or even possible.

Here is my `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="row">
        ...
        <h6><b>Location:</b> <%# Item.Location%>, <%# Item.Postcode%></h6> 
        <asp:Label ID="lbPostcodeDistance" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

How else could I show an additional dynamically calculated value, exactly where the label is in the `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: When you are calling this `ListView1_GetData` method?

Comment: @RahulSingh the `ListView1_GetData`, which is the `SelectMethod` is implicitly called when ever the page postbacks. I never directly call the method

Comment: Okk got it _ASP.NET 4.5_ :)

Comment: @RahulSingh sorry I should have mentioned it above! :-)

Comment: So if I have understood you correctly, `Location` & `Postcode` are properties of `Walk` object and you have `dis` (probably as a string) in `InRangeWalks` object which you wish to bind to the label `lbPostcodeDistance`?

Comment: Yes `Location` & `Postcode` are properties for a `Walk`. At runtime, user enters a postcode, which I then pass in a method and store result in `dis`. I then order the walks in the `inRangeWalks` list by inserting my custom data-structure. `InRangeWalks` stores `Dis` (a `double`) and `Walk` object. So yes, simply I want the `dis` which is in `InRangeWalks` object binded to the label `lbPostcodeDistance`

Comment: Hey I still have one doubt, `ListView1_GetData()` must be executed at the initail page load itself right? That means you are doing the calculation and storing the output in `dis` before hand itself then why not return the complete `InRangeWalks` object instead of just `Walk`?

Comment: @RahulSingh `ListView1_GetData()` is executed at initial page load. I then have a dropdown menu, and depending what is selected, the conditional statements in `ListView1_GetData()` executes certain code, thus showing the relevant results. Yes, returning `InRangeWalks` object would work (I assume I could then access the property with `eval`, but the `ListView` will not take an `InRangeWalks` objects, due to the method signature being: `IEnumerable<...> ListView1_GetData()`

Comment: Okay can't you change the method signature to return `IEnumerable<InRangeWalks>`? Also do you want to update any specific label or all the labels will have same value?

Comment: @RahulSingh I could do in theory. Although the data structure `InRangeWalks` is only used by one of the 4-5 options. The additional param `Dis` would be `null for all other options, which seems a bit untidy. The label would be always in the same position, but it would have a different value for every item (just like every item has a different location or postcode)

Comment: Well in that case the data structure of `InRangeWalks` should be like this - a single property for `dis` & a `List<Walk>` to hold all walk objects. But I am not sure how much control you have on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I actually ended up using Rahul's advice in the comments, and made my `ListView` use my custom data source.

Was a little bit of a pain to get it up and running but it's now working great!

If someone wants to implement their own data structure, just remember on the `ASPX` page change the `ItemType` to the new structure i.e. `ItemType="MyProject.Folder.ClassName"`. And then you can access the property with model binding like: `text=<%# Item.MyObject.Property %>`